# Can't access folder from subdomain?

Tags: html, directory, subdomain

So I thought that you could access a folder in public_html from a subdomain.

Example:

```
Folder name = "test", URL = "test.mydoma.in"
```

Is this an actual thing? If so can I fix it?

Im running cPanel from clovux.net

Comment: Where does that line come from? htaccess? Also urls should start with `http://`

Comment: Its not a real line, I meant if I had a folder named "test" I could go to "http://test.mydomain.com"

Comment: I go to said URL, and I get: test.s*******.com'’s server DNS address could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the issue was I needed to make a subdomain with the test document root.